# Get customer details on my account tab when click on "edit" in frontend -magento

Tags: magento

Need to fetch Customer details(name,addresss etc)  if customer logs into my account and edits  customer information only after placed orders. I found this
/design/frontend/.../default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml as it displays customer information. Can any one suggest how to work with this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, this is just a view that prints out the information. The block related with this is /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php. Check in there for business logic layer.